# Running windows apps on Ubuntu (wine?)

Tags: windows, wine

Hello brothers & sisters in Linux!
I have a question concerning running windows applications on Ubuntu.
I was using Ubuntu for a long time, but then I had to convert back to Windows because I found out that Wine didn't make it to run some applications as Photoshop, After Effects, Vegas Pro, Dreamweaver, etc...

I'm asking you guys for a help how to run these programs in these days (sort of speak). 
Has there been any major update for Wine that eliminated those emulation problems? Will Wine run all of my applications today? If not, how can I run these applications on Ubuntu?

Thank you in advance! Really appreciate your help!

A.

Comment: You should search solutions for every particular piece of program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wine has been updated but also you can use it with PlayOnLinux which abstracts better IMHO and has pre-configurations.

Comment: So are you saying that it is better to use PlayOnLinux than Wine? Or rather use both, but for these applications as Photoshop, Dreamweaver, etc... it is better to use POL?

Comment: Play On Linux always as a first solution, it's better in dependency management, uninstalls and pre-configurations.